# Searching in a list of lists

Tags: c#, list, xamarin

I have a list which also contains a list which contains some objects:

```
var elements = new List<ElementGroup>()
            {
                new ElementGroup("WIRES")
                {
                    new Element() {Name = "Wires", Image = "wires.jpg"}
                },
                new ElementGroup("GROUND")
                {
                    new Element() {Name = "Ground", Image = "ground.jpg"}
                }
            };
```

ElementGroup class:

```
public class ElementGroup : List<Element>
```

I want to apply Linq query to all `Element` objects from all `ElementGroup` lists but if I do it like this:

```
elements.Where(c => c.Family.Contains(searchText.ToUpper()));
```

it applies the query on `ElementGroup` lists.

Comment: Side note: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: First, reformat your question if possible. You want to select all elements if one of the element matches the predicate or select only which matches the predicate?.

Comment: What type is `c` in your example? I don't see any class with the property `Family`

Comment: @vbnet3d `c` is the element of the list. Checkout linq about `Func`

Comment: Don't use `ToUpper` for comparisons. Use the `StringComparison` option. You'll most likely want to use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa no, it's a valid question. That `Family` must be a property of the `ElementGroup` class, but that class isn't given in the question, and none of the given code fills in such a `Family` property.

Comment: @Nyerguds there is no `StringComparision` parameter for `Contains` he can to use `IndexOf` with `StringComparision`

Comment: Point. Still, hard to understand without knowing what type that `Family` even _is_.

Comment: Family is a property of ElementGroup class

Comment: Please write expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is how you can get List of Element from List<ElementGroup>.

List<Element> result = 
    elements.SelectMany(elementGroup =>             
        elementGroup.Where(element=>element.Name=="Wires")).ToList();
```

Comment: PS: Sai's answer is not complete but correct, not sure why his answer is down voted.

Answer (score -1):

Use SelectMany which flattens the inner list.

Code might look like this 
elements.SelectMany(s => s.Elements)

And you can work on this list of elements

EDIT:

Also, consider having a list of Elements "in" ElementGroup rather than inheriting. Then using SelectMany becomes the natural choice.

Comment: @Ionut Gabriel Pitigoi - Any specific reason you are inheriting and not having List<Element> as a property in ElementGroup?